# Android Maps v2 : add multiple markers to google mapfragment

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to add 2 markers to the google map with the following code. It shows only one location instead of two. Can anyone look at it and comment ? I saw that the location values are distinct with a debugger.

public void updateMapWithNewLocation() {

```
    Marker marker1 = null;
    Marker marker2 = null;

    LatLng latLng1 = null;
    LatLng latLng2 = null;

    if (mMyLocation != null) {

        latLng1 = new LatLng(mMyLocation.getLatitude(), mMyLocation.getLongitude());

        MarkerOptions myMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng1)
                .title("me");
        marker1 = mMap.addMarker(myMarkerOptions);
    }

    if (mFriendLocation != null) {
        latLng2 = new LatLng(mMyLocation.getLatitude(), mMyLocation.getLongitude());

        MarkerOptions friendMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng2)
                .title("friend");
        marker2 = mMap.addMarker(friendMarkerOptions);
    }


    List<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(marker1 != null){
        markerList.add(marker1);
    }
    if(marker2 != null) {
        markerList.add(marker2);
    }

    zoomToShowAllMarkers(markerList);
}

private void zoomToShowAllMarkers(List<Marker> markers) {
    if ( markers == null || markers.size() < 1)
        return;

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker marker : markers) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }

    for (Marker m : markers) {
        builder.include(m.getPosition());
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bounds.getCenter(), 10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did to zoom with bounds:

```
map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLoaded() {
                        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20);
                        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    }
                });
```

The `onMapLoaded()` makes the zooming done after the map got loaded.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions and looking at it.

I had a copy/paste error of using myLocation instead of friendLocation

this particular line:

> > latLng2 = new LatLng(mMyLocation.getLatitude() mMyLocation.getLongitude());  <-- should use mFriendLocation instead of mMyLocation.

Sorry for the trouble.